# Parsear achivo TXT en C

Tags: c

El ejercicio consiste en dado un archivo `TXT` creado con el block de notas
que el programa lea y parsee de manera variable detectando cada campo del archivo de texto los reconozca y así poder usarlos o mostrarlos. Mi problema es que el `while` saltea  como si el archivo no existiera pero si existe. Les agradezco desde ya su respuesta

**Main:**

```
#include"prototipos.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *archtxt;


    archtxt= fopen("empleados.txt","r+t");

    if(!archtxt)
    {
        printf(" no se pudo acceder al archivo");
        return 1;
    }

    txt_a_parsear(archtxt);

    fclose(archtxt);

    return 0;
}
```

**Header**:

```
#include"prototipos.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *archtxt;


    archtxt= fopen("empleados.txt","r+t");

    if(!archtxt)
    {
        printf(" no se pudo acceder al archivo");
        return 1;
    }

    txt_a_parsear(archtxt);

    fclose(archtxt);

    return 0;
}
```

**Funciones.c**:

```
#include"prototipos.h"

void txt_a_parsear(FILE *txt)
{
    t_empleado emp;
    char linea[TAM];

    fgets(linea,TAM,txt);

    while(!feof(txt))
    {
        parseo_txt_var(linea,&emp);
        fgets(linea,TAM,txt);

    }
}

void parseo_txt_var(char * linea,t_empleado *emp)
{

    char *act = strchr(linea,'\n');

    *act='\0';
    act=strrchr(linea,'|');

    emp->sexo=*(act+1);

    *act='\0';
    act=strrchr(linea,'|');
    sscanf(act+1,"%f",&emp->sueldo);

    *act='\0';
    act=strrchr(linea,'|');

    sscanf(act+1,"%d/%d/%d",&emp->fnac.dia,&emp->fnac.mes,&emp->fnac.ano);

    *act='\0';
    act=strrchr(linea,'|');

    strncpy(emp->apyn,act+1,sizeof(emp->apyn));

    *act='\0';


     sscanf(linea,"%d",&emp->dni);
}
```

Comment: Una consulta: probaste haciendo el fopen así  archtxt = fopen("empleados.txt","r+t"); ? Y veo que repetiste el main y el header, podrías corregirlo por favor?

Comment: Si dentro del while haces un printf de la cadena leída (algo como printf("%s\r\n", linea); ) ¿Muestra el contenido de la línea por pantalla?. Si es así, entonces el error lo tienes al leer del txt (problemas de permisos, ruta, etc.), sino lo tienes en parseo_txt_var.

Comment: Pega el header correctamente por favor

Answer (score 1):

Puede que estés invocando [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) así que cualquier cosa podría pasar (funcionar, no funcionar, funcionar incorrectamente, o [invocar demonios que saldrían disparados de tus fosas nasales](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

Por lo que puedo ver estás usando un modo de lectura extendido (`"r+"`) al abrir el archivo a la vez que le pides modo texto (`"t"`). Sin embargo el modo texto no lo veo referenciado en ninguna documentación de `fopen`:

- `fopen` en [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).
- `fopen` en [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx).
- `fopen` en [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

La única documentación que hace referencia al modo `"t"` está en cplusplus.com y escrita de pasada como algo no oficial de ningún compilador (traducción y resaltado míos):

> Si hay caracteres adicionales en la secuencia, **el comportamiento depende de la implementación de la librería**: algunas implementaciones pueden ignorar los caracteres adicionales de manera que por ejemplo una `"t"` adicional (a veces usada para explicitar modo texto) se acepte.

Si consultamos el [estándar de C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) vemos los siguientes modos aceptados (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 7.19.5.3 la función `fopen`
>
> ...
>
> 3. El argumento `mode` apunta a una cadena de caracteres. Si la cadena apunta a uno de los siguientes el archivo se abre en el modo indicado. En caso contrario **el comportamiento es indefinido**:
>
>    - `r` abre un archivo para lectura
>    - `w` trunca a cero o crea un archivo de texto para escritura
>    - `a` añade; abre o crea un archivo de texto para escribir al final del archivo
>    - `rb` abre en modo binario para lectura
>    - `wb` trunca a cero o crea un archivo en modo binario para escribir al final del archivo
>    - `ab` añade; abre o crea un archivo en modo binario para escribir al final del archivo
>    - `r+` abre un archivo de texto para actualizar (leer y escribir)
>    - `w+` trunca a cero o crea un archivo de texto para actualizar
>    - `a+` añade; abre o crea un archivo de texto para actualizar, el puntero de escritura se sitúa al final del archivo

Así que cabe la posibilidad de no te funcione por el modo `"t"`.